# .NET PDF Creator Tool with Robust Headers/Footers

Tags: pdf, .net, pdf-generation, vb.net

I am in need of a tool which allows me to create high-quality PDF files in VB.Net.

The tool needs to be able to create Headers and Footers that can be modified during run time (I can't just copy from an existing template) and it needs to be able to create clean looking information tables.

I am working in a professional capacity here, so I am not exactly looking for freeware.  Feel free to suggest tools that cost money.

Comment: See my answer here, a lot of the paid software is doing the exact same thing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658645/495455

Answer (score 0):

PDFTron PDFNet SDK for Windows provides a VB.Net API, and a variety of ways to generate PDF files, for which you have full control.

Here are the samples I think you would be most interested in.

- [GDI+ to PDF](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples?platforms=windows#pdfdc) : See [second part here](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/vb/PDFDCTest/?platforms=windows), for PDFDCEX usage.
- [XAML to PDF](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples?platforms=windows#xaml2pdf) : Just [C# sample](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/cs/XAML2PDFTest?platforms=windows), but translating to VB should
  be straight forward.
- [ElementBuilder](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples?platforms=windows#elementbuilder) : [This](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/vb/ElementBuilderTest/?platforms=windows) API, which can
  be used to post-process the outputs from above, gives full control
  over the exact appearance of the PDF.

It also possible to convert HTML or DOCX to PDF using PDFNet.

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Essential PDF](https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/pdf) can be used to create high quality PDF documents.

Working with [headers and footers](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-headers-and-footers) is supported.

[image: Essential PDF Header and Footer]

Multiple options are available for working with [Tables](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-tables).

[image: Essential PDF Table]

[Live samples](https://aspdotnetcore.syncfusion.com/PDF/Default#/material) for ASP.NET Core, but the libraries are supported on Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC, WinRT, Windows Phone, Windows store universal and Xamarin applications as well.

VB.NET code is provided for all code samples.

A single license for the File Formats Edition costs $995. The whole product is also available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.